# How to install Obinskit on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, keyboard

My friend gave me his [Anne Pro 2](https://www.annepro.net/products/anne-pro-2) a 60% mechanical keyboard so I was trying to download and install it's driver **Obinskit** on my computer Ubuntu 20.04 but I ran into a problem. I found that by searching google, there were others had the same problem but I can't find a great solution. I saw this two pages[1](https://www.forkingbytes.com/blog/installing-anne-pro-2-companion-software-on-fedora-linux/)[2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/obinskit) that give me a chance to install **Obinskit** but they don't work correctly.

Are someone know how to install it correctly or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: The two pages you refers to are for Fedora and Arch Linux,  not Ubuntu.

Comment: This could be an inteesting question. However, few users may know what Anne Pro 2 is, and what the software Obinskit is, because it is not standard available in the Ubuntu software center. So please add information about these two unclear items to your question: use "edit". Please also note this is a Q&A site to collect questions and answers for the perusal of future users, not a user forum. You plea for help (last sentences) can thus be removed.

Comment: thank you for reminding me!!